# Evaluating auto correlation strength (Gamma)

Tags: autocorrelation, correlation

I'm working on Cognitive Radio in TV Band Spectrum.  I need to sense the presence of signal in a particular spectrum. I have to sample the incoming signal (say 1000 samples) and I have to find the auto correlation strength for a smoothing factor L(means my sample will be 0 to L-1 samples delayed). I have assumed a smoothing factor of 10. How to find the autocorrelation strength. Gamma L.

Comment: What is the problem? Don't you know formula for autocorrelation (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autocorrelation.html) ?